# JqModal fade in the popup?

Tags: jquery, jqmodal

I am using the plugin jqModal which I have working just fine, however I want to make my jqModal dialog/overlay box fadeIn when called. I find it a bit "in your face" when I click to show it as it appears very quickly I don't want to put users off.

Is there anyway I can apply a fadeIn of some sort to my code? This is what I am using to activate the jqModal. Thanks in advance!

```
$('#popup').jqm({ajax: 'news', trigger: '.trigger'});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that jqModal does not support animation effects. The plugin is very loosely written. Therefore, I would suggest that you migrate to a different plugin.

As a suggestion, try **[this](http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal/)**.

*(Note: I would put this in comments, as it isn't really an answer - but I can't. Getting there...)*

Answer (score 1):

Its a little late for this,  but...

Search for the following text in the plugin code:

```
h.w.show();
```

Replace with

```
h.w.fadeIn(600, function() { });
```

You can also do the same thing with the default close functionality:

```
h.w.hide();
```

Replace with

```
h.w.fadeOut(600, function () { });
```